# Preloader to load external SWF without PROGRESS and COMPLETE events

Tags: flash, external, preloader

I have created the following preloader saved as "preloader.swf" that loads an external SWF file as follows:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("main.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(req);

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, showPreloader);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, showProgress);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showContent);

var preloader:Preloader = new Preloader();

function showPreloader(event:Event):void 
{
    addChild(preloader);
    preloader.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (preloader.width / 2);
    preloader.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (preloader.height / 2);
}

function showProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void 
{
    var percent:Number = event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal;
    preloader.percentage.text = Math.round(percent * 100) + "%";
    preloader.bar.width = 300 * percent;
}

function showContent(event:Event):void 
{
    removeChild(preloader);
    addChild(loader);
}
```

I was reading to try avoid the PROGRESS and COMPLETE events since these events don't work 100% of the time.

Now my question is this: is there a way of how I can go about to have the same functionality of loading an external SWF file (as above) but WITHOUT using the PROGRESS and COMPLETE events?

If so, can anyone suggest me what coding to add/change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HAve you tried with a Timer? You check at every interval is the SWF is loaded entirely or not.

However , PROGRESS and COMPLETE events should always work. What's not working in your project?

Comment: Whilst testing it locally, the preloader never gives me any trouble. But when I uploaded it online, the preloader loads faster than usual in a jagged manner, or freezes at times. Once the preloader hangs and the site is refreshed, or the cache is cleared, the site will work perfectly as supposed to, i.e. loads slower than before as intended. The strange thing that I can't manage to understand and solve is that only when the preloader has froze/hung and the site is refreshed, or the cache is cleared, will the entire site work perfectly as supposed to with no glitches or lock-ups!